# CodeIgniter Simple Login in Bootstrap Form

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new to CodeIgniter and trying to sortout a simple login form using the framework.

**FORM View**

```
   <form action="login" method="post">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username"  value="">
   <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" value="">
   <div style="color:red;" class="col pl-1">
   <?php
    echo $error;
    ?>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="signin">Login</button>
   </form>
```

**Controller**

```
class Loginauth extends CI_Controller 
{

    public function index()
    {
    $this->load->view('auth');
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $data=array();
        if($this->input->post('signin'))
        {
                $u=$this->input->post('username');
                $p=$this->input->post('password');
                if($u=='admin' && $p=='123')
                {
                 redirect('loginauth/dashboard');
                }
                else
                {
                    $data['error']="<h3 style='color:red'>Invalid login details</h3>";
                }

        }
     $this->load->view('auth',@$data);

    }

    function dashboard()
    {
    $this->load->view('success');
    }
}
```

When I submit the login page, it is redirected to

`localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.10/index.php/login`
(without username and password), but nothing happens. 
Could you please help me to sort this thing?

Comment: Hi, I think you should declare your variable `$data` as array such as `$data = array();`

Comment: I declared the array and edited the post with that, but didnt help. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Inside else statement, try to add `$this->load->vars($data);` below `$data['error']`

Comment: Added that, but no luck. I was wondering whether the form action is right? Because when I click submit without username and password, it is redirected to localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.10/index.php/login

Comment: @Zendie, it should be action='loginauth/login'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load the form helper and form_validation library first.

```
public function login()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required'); 

      $data['error'] = validation_errors();

      if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
           $this->load->view('auth',@$data);
       }else{

            $u=$this->input->post('username');
            $p=$this->input->post('password');
            if($u=='admin' && $p=='123')
            {
             redirect('loginauth/dashboard');
            }
            else
            {
                $data['error']="<h3 style='color:red'>Invalid login details</h3>";
                $this->load->view('auth',@$data);
            }
       }


}
```

your form action should be: `action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/loginauth/login') ?>"`. that's it, let me know the result.

Comment: I did that in the config file. I am getting login page form.

Comment: @Zendie, i updated my answer. not that good structured answer but i just show you the basics.

Comment: thank you, no changes. I had added base url in the config file. auth.php is in views folder. Loginauth.php in controllers. Is there anything else I need to do? Seems like form action is not right. when I submit without username and password the page is redirected to localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.10/index.php/login from the page localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.10/index.php/loginauth

Comment: When changed the action loginauth/login, second time when I press the submit buttom it is redirected to localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.10/index.php/loginauth/loginauth/login

Comment: did you set up a custom route for it?. can you show me also your base_url?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193294/discussion-between-curiosity-and-zendie).